# Expected number of isolated vertices in a graph and an upper bound on divergence from expected value

Tags: graph-theory, expected-value, random

I am presented with a randomly generated graph $G$, and am trying to 1) calculate the expected number of isolated vertices in $G$; and 2) prove an upper bound on the probability that the expected number of isolated vertices deviates from the expected value by a certain amount.

Formally $G$ is a random graph with $n$ vertices and $cn$ edges for a constant $c > 0$.
$G$ is generated as follows: let $P$ be the set of all $\binom{n}{2}$
possible pairs of vertices. Pick a pair uniformly, add the edge between said pair to $G$; then delete the pair from $P$. Repeat  until $cn$ edges have been added to $G$.

Now, if we define $X$ as the number of isolated vertices in $G$. How can I calculate $E[X]$ and show that:

$$P(|X-E(X)| \geq 2\lambda \sqrt{cn}) \leq 2e^{-\lambda^2/2}$$